# Watching Intermediate Calculations or Estimate Remaining Time in Eliminate Command

Tags: polynomials, monitoring

I want to use `Eliminate` commands to 70 coupled multivariable polynomial equations, but the code is too slow. (It does not show result after 30 minutes in my laptop.)

In my code, I want to find a condition on parameters such that the $4\times 4$ matrix $h(px, py)$ and $h(px+ps, pyy)$ has a common eigenvalue and common eigenvector. This condition can be written as a polynomial system. The following code gives background definitions. In particular, `cond` contains 70 polynomial conditions.

Note:The working mechanism of the code is nicely explained in the following link:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4075581/finding-common-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-via-commutative-algebra/4076087?noredirect=1#comment8423617_4076087

The following is my code:

```
$Assumptions = {Element[px, Reals], 
   Element[ps, Reals], \[CapitalDelta] > 0, 0 < \[Phi] < 2*Pi, 
       Element[\[Mu], Reals], v > 0, 0 < e < \[CapitalDelta], W > 0}; 
h = ArrayFlatten[{{v*px*PauliMatrix[1] + 
       v*py*PauliMatrix[2] - \[Mu]*IdentityMatrix[2], 
             \[CapitalDelta]*Exp[I*\[Phi]]*
       IdentityMatrix[2]}, {\[CapitalDelta]*Exp[(-I)*\[Phi]]*
       IdentityMatrix[2], 
             -(v*px*PauliMatrix[1] + 
         v*py*PauliMatrix[2] - \[Mu]*IdentityMatrix[2])}}] /. 
       {v -> 1}; 
totalmat = ArrayFlatten[{{h - e*IdentityMatrix[4]}, 
         {(h /. {\[Phi] -> 0, px -> px + ps, py -> pyy}) - 
             e*IdentityMatrix[4]}}]; 
matlist = (totalmat[[#1, {1, 2, 3, 4}]] & ) /@ 
   Subsets[Range[8], {4}]; 
cond = (Det[#1] == 0 & ) /@ matlist;
```

And then, finally, I want to eliminate px, py, and pyy:

```
Eliminate[cond, {px, py, pyy}]
```

This part is very slow! I want either of the following:

1. Estimate the remaining time to finish the computation.
2. See the intermediate result of calculation.

How can I do either of the above one?

Comment: (1) `Eliminate` is using dated technology. For such a task you'd do better with `GroebnerBasis[...,MonomialOrder->EliminationOrder]`.

Comment: (2) There is no plausible way to know how "close" a Groebner basis computation might be to completion. So the answer to the question asked is "No".

Comment: (3) Even with the best of under-the-hood code, it seems like the size of this computation will put it out of reach. I wonder if there might be different formulations though. This is sometimes the case when dealing with eigenvalue questions: one formulation might involve quadratics while another becomes a linear algebra problem.

Comment: ...and (4) It is an odd coincidence that you have an eigenvalue problem, given that your parents named you "eigenvalue". (Sorry, couldn't let that one pass...)

Comment: Now to look at the underlying problem. As noted in your math.SE post, you can deduce a common eigenvalue condition from a resultant computation involving just two polynomials. This should (a) be tractable and (b) give finitely many values to check. You could then brute-force check each to see if they also share an eigenvector.